# How to prove that a sphere in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ can't be a parametric surface

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples

Given his definition of parametric surface

> let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ open, homeomorphic to an open disk and let $ P : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ a smooth injective function s.t. the jacobian in every point of $\Omega $ has maximal rank, then $ P $ is a parametric surface.

I need to prove that the sphere is not a parametric surface (image of a a parametric surface). On my notes there is written "it can't be, just because a sphere is not homeomorphic to a disk of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $".

But I don't see why homeomorphisms are involved here,  because P, in general, is not an homeo on its image (there are counterexamples) instead it is a local homeo, but this is ok to me. Maybe this fact involves some notions about fundamental groups or homology groups but I don't know results that don't involve homeomorphisms or deformation retracts between two topological spaces (and according to me this is not the case). 
Just to make clear, I know where the other usual parametrizations fails in this case, but i can't see a general scheme to help me point out the main reason.

Comment: $S^2$ is compact.

Comment: Mmh i know that the image of a compact is compact but no the preimage. I'm surely missing something but i don't know what

Comment: I'm sorry and after the first look of the question, I thought it is about how to prove that open disc is not homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is indeed a subtle one. Usually, the definition of a parametric surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ one encounters is (the image of) a smooth injective map $P \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $dP_p \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ has maximal rank (here, 2) at each $p \in \Omega$ and that $P$ is a homeomorphism onto its image (endowed with the subspace topology). See for example Do Carmo's Curves and Surfaces. Such a parametric surface is called an **embedded parametric surface** and $P$ is called an embedding. It is clear that $S^2$ cannot be an embedded parametric surface because for example $S^2$ is compact while $\Omega$ is not. However, if one doesn't require the condition that $P$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, one is left with what is sometimes called an **immersed parametric surface** (and $P$ is called an immersion). For example, if we look at $P \colon (-\pi, \pi) \times (-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, given by $P(t,s) = (\sin(2t), \sin(t),s)$, we get the following surface:

[image]

This surface is not an embedded parametric surface because the map $P$ is not a homeomorphism onto its image (for example, because the image is not simply connected) but it is an immersed parametric surface. Generally, it is not trivial to decide whether a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be an immersed parametric surface or not because one precisely cannot use "naive" topological arguments.

However, one can show that $S^2$ cannot be an immersed parametric surface as follows. Consider your parametrization $P \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ as a smooth map between manifolds and note that $P(\Omega) = S^2$ on the level of sets. Considering $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ as an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$), one can show that the by restricting the codomain of $P$ to $S^2$, one is still left with a smooth map $P \colon \Omega \rightarrow S^2$ **between manifolds**. This is Corollary 5.30 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Using the chain rule, one can see that the rank of $dP_p \colon T_p\Omega \rightarrow T_{P(p)}(S^2)$ is two for all $p \in \Omega$. That is, $P \colon \Omega \rightarrow S^2$ is a smooth bijection with full rank and thus by the inverse function theorem must be a local diffeomorphism and (since $P$ is injective and surjective) a diffeomorphism. In particular, $P$ is a homeomorphism. But $S^2$ is compact while $\Omega$ is not - a contradiction.

More generally, if $A \subseteq M$ is a subset of a smooth manifold such that with the induced subset topology $\tau$, $(A,\tau)$ has the structure of a smooth manifold, then the set $A$ has a unique topology and a unique smooth structure such that the inclusion $A \subseteq M$ is an immersion (that is, such that $A$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$). For more details, see Warner's book Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds where this is discussed in the context of manifolds.

Comment: Good answer, but i think it left the main point unsolved. Clearly $S^2 $ can't be an embedded parametric surface (at least according to the requirement on $\Omega $) but we are left with the question "it is an imbedded one?" Anyway, good explanatory answer!

Comment: Arg, yeah, I thought I could answer the question avoiding the usage of the language of submanifolds and smooth maps between them but this clearly doesn't work. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Immersed not imbedded :)

Comment: Yeah that sounds good. Just one question, the open mapping theorem which i studied in functional analysis involves linear (and continuous) application. so i guess you are applying it to the differential of P, showing that is an open map. But how do you conclude that P is a diffeomorphism hence an homeomorphisms?

Comment: I'm using the open mapping theorem of advanced calculus (which is a particular case of the implicit function theorem), not of functional analysis. The statement is that if $F \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p \in \Omega$ is a point such that the $n \times n$ matrix $dF_p$ is non-singular, then there are neighborhoods $U \subseteq \Omega$ of $p$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ of $F(p)$ such that $F|_{U} \colon U \rightarrow V$ is a diffeomorphism. This extends readily to smooth maps between manifolds.

Comment: (Maybe I should've called it the inverse function theorem... Also, the statement that the restriction of the codomain of a smooth map to an embedded submanifold is still smooth is not entirely trivial and itself uses the implicit function theorem).

Comment: Ok, but this is a local condition right? To conclude that $\Omega $ is compact hence absurd don't you need a "global" (defined over all S^2) homeomorphism? I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question :(

Comment: If you have a one to one and onto map $f$ between manifolds that is a local diffeomorphism, it must be a global diffeomorphism because $f^{-1}$ is defined, and you know that locally it is smooth.

Comment: Perfect:) now al the pieces come together. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why an immersion $P \colon \Omega \rightarrow S^2$ should be a "smooth bijection with full rank". The immersion illustrated in your figure is not injective. The proof that there is no immersion $P:\ \Omega\to S^2$ is elusive.

Comment: Why is it not injective? If $P(t,s) = P(t',s')$ then $s = s'$ and $\sin(t) = \sin(t')$ and $\sin(2t) = \sin(2t')$ which forces $t = t'$..